# Printing an image from table with plsql to html in base64 doesn't work

Tags: oracle, plsql

I might have exagerated the title a bit but when something works sometimes, I consider it as it does not work.

Basically I am storing in a table images by using 3 columns.

- IMAGE_RIGHT   BLOB (used to store the image)
- MIMETYPE_RIGHT    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) (used to store the mimetype)
- NOM_IMAGE_RIGHT   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) (used to store the filename)

And this is how I displaythe image.

```
if V_IMAGE_RIGHT is not null then
                    BEGIN
                        htp.p('<img style="float: right;" src="data:' || v_mimetype_right || ';base64,' || apex_web_service.blob2clobbase64(v_image_right) || '" height="100px">');
                    exception
                        when others then
                            htp.p('Err : ' || SQLERRM);
                    END; 
                  end if;
```

In most cases it works and with svgs too but sometimes some files just seem not to work and I get this error "**ORA-06502: PL/SQL**".

I tried with one of my none working images to get it's content in base64 by doing a select query and then I created a html file to print the image also by using the base64 content and it worked on my html file but the same process automated by my procedure does not work somehow.

Comment: What is the full error message? I imagine the string concatenation is just too big for some files as the result would hit the 32k limit? You might need to split the CLOB up and print each line separately (which should be fairly simple given the short line lengths for base64-encoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it.
As the comment from Alex Poole said htp.p has a limit of 32k characters.

So this is how I did it.

First I created those 3 variables :

```
v_offset     INTEGER := 1;
v_chunk_size INTEGER := 32000;
v_chunk      VARCHAR2(32000);
```

Then changed my way of displaying the image :

```
    if V_IMAGE_LEFT is not null then
                    BEGIN
                        htp.p('<img src="data:' || v_mimetype_left || ';base64,');
                        WHILE v_offset <= LENGTH(v_image_left) LOOP
                          v_chunk := SUBSTR(v_image_left, v_offset, v_chunk_size);
                    
                          -- afficher chaque segment à l'aide de HTP.P
                          HTP.P(v_chunk);
                    
                          v_offset := v_offset + v_chunk_size;
                       END LOOP;
                        htp.p('" height="100px">');
                    END;    
                  end if;
```

Comment: Note that htp.p generates a newline character after the output. This could cause unwanted side effects. The procedure htp.prn does not print a newline character. In a loop it's advised to use htp.prn - see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/HTP.html#GUID-D6DEE56F-ECA5-460E-976D-B613FEB5EB0A)